# Remove Edit Lines Button on a certain page layout only

Tags: custom-button, page-layout, cpq

Has anyone tried removing the edit lines button on a page layout? I was able to remove it on a certain PL but it is still being displayed? Not sure it can be deactivated but that would remove it on all layouts anyway. Just need it in on some specific PL

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details like which button are you talking about? Are you using classic or lightning?

Comment: Hi, the Edit lines button on the record page. The one used to access the QLE, I think this button is CPQ standard button if Im not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding a filter on the lightning record page for the Edit lines Button.